# Select Next duplicate Listbox item.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, listbox, listboxitem

i Tried Several Time, To Select next duplicate Line, and changed it in same time,

For Example,

> ListBox1 item's :

```
1
1
1
2
1
3
4
5
```

MY Code (Button1):

> By that it will change First "1" in top line, next , it will select
>   another "1" and will change it too , To "Changed" ... Etc.

```
  If TextBox1.Text = "1" Then

        ListBox1.SelectedItem = TextBox1.Text

        Dim indx As Integer = ListBox1.SelectedItem
        If indx <> -1 Then
            ListBox1.Select(indx, TextBox1.Text.Length  
        If ListBox1.SelectedItem <> "" Then
                ListBox1.SelectedIndices = "Changed"
            End If
        End If

    End If
```

I tried this , But it selected all duplicate items, and i want single select every button click.

```
Dim s As String = Me.TextBox1.Text
    Dim lb As ListBox = Me.ListBox1
    lb.SelectedIndex = -1
    If s.Length <> -1 Then


        For i As Integer = 0 To lb.Items.Count - 1

            Try
                If lb.Items(i).ToString.Contains(s) Then
                    lb.SelectedIndices.Add(i)


                Else

                End If
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

        Next
    End If
```

every button 1 click will change 1 duplicate item lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if i understand what you need but try this:

```
   Dim s As String = Me.TextBox1.Text
    Dim lb As ListBox = Me.ListBox1

    Dim selected = lb.SelectedIndex
    If s.Length <> -1 Then


        For i As Integer = selected + 1 To lb.Items.Count - 1
            If lb.Items(i).ToString = s Then
                lb.SelectedIndex = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

Comment: You Number 1 , this what i need To make, i Mark As answered, Big thanks.